# how to show all attributes even filters applied in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

how to show all attributes even filters applied i.e., if we click on like category options then some options get cleared so I want to display all filters whether if we choose another option also.

Comment: You can try it https://www.manadev.com/magento-extensions/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes should be set to this:

**Use In Layered Navigation = Filterable (no results)**